# How to send EMR(Spark) Logs to AWS Cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, log4j, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I am using the Log4j with appender `"com.kdgregory.log4j.aws.CloudWatchAppender"` for my application logs. The logs are being received in AWS Cloudwatch when I run it in EC2 or Lambda. But if I run the app built using Spark with same classes, none of these logs are delivered to the Cloudwatch. Does anyone know how to send Log4j logs to AWS Cloudwatch from the Spark application.